# How to output a random set of observations from a SAS data set

Tags: sas

I have a data set that selects random numbers from a uniform distribution. How do you only output those row indices? I basically want to select a random set of rows from a SAS data set.

```
data Unif(keep=u x k n m);
call streaminit(123);
a = -1; b = 1;
Min = 1; Max = 28000000;
do i = 1 to &NObs;
   u = rand("Uniform");    /* U[0,1] */
   x = a + (b-a)*u;        /* U[a,b] */
   k = ceil( Max*u );      /* uniform integer in 1..Max */
   n = floor( (1+Max)*u ); /* uniform integer in 0..Max */
   m = min + floor((1+Max-Min)*u); /* uniform integer in Min..Max */
   output;
end;
keep k
run;
     *not sure about this part;
    data final;
     set final;
     where obs in (k);
   run;
```

Comment: Are you just trying to randomly sample some records?  What's the high level problem, in detail but in English (not code)?

Comment: Yes I am just trying to randomly get 10 observations from my data set.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use `PROC SURVEYSELECT`.

```
proc surveyselect data=final out=selected seed=123 n=10;
run;
```

Or something along those lines depending on how you want to run it - [the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#surveyselect_toc.htm) has a lot of detail on the various options for how to perform the sampling.

If you want to do it in the datastep, you need to be running the code from `Unif` inside the second datastep, in some fashion.  I don't entirely follow what it's trying to do; if that's a form of k/n sampling, search 'SAS k/n sampling' and you'll find lots out there as it's a common question, but the general approach is

```
data final_selected;
set final;
... code to determine if it should be selected...
if (condition); *subsetting if;
run;
```

Comment: Is there an observation index variable that is created? For my if statement, I want a statement which says if obs in(these random indexes), then output;

Comment: That's not a good way to do this.  Both of the above choose your 10 (or whatever) for you without that sort of statement, but in an equivalent method (choosing based on a uniform random distribution).